# Generating dynamic Check boxes in Lotus Notes Client Application

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a dialog box with computed field. Based on that computed field i want to generate two check box(es). For example, If computed field contains 4 values then i want to generate 8 check boxes.
Note : This is not a web application. I'm using LotusScript to open dialog box. 
Appreciate if anyone help me to resolve this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7hW2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one check box field and calculate the choices with a formula based on your field. If resulting list has e.g. 8 elements then you'll have 8 check boxes in your dialog box.

[image]

Comment: in this case, we will have one column of check boxes for the computed field value. but i want to generate two columns of check boxes based on the computed value

Comment: Please find the screenshot,

Comment: Then change number of columns from 1 to 2.

Comment: I have added sample screen knut, it will help to get a clear picture

Comment: In this case, create two check box fields and use white color and white background color. This way the names behind every check box are invisible.